# Programically get the system name of named pipe

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, named-pipes

I am writing a inter-process comunication using WCF NetNamedPipeBinding.

My goal is to have service running at "net.pipe://localhost/service", so I running the simplest host:

```
host = new ServiceHost(contract, new Uri[] { "net.pipe://localhost" });
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IContract),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "service");
host.Open();
```

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx 
the name is hidden behind system-generated guid.

And here comes the question.

Is there any possible way to get the name generated by system (guid) inside my program, so I could get path like "\Device\NamedPipe\GUID", like in the procexp, so it will be easier to sniff it?
(Except running sys internals executables in separate process and parsing its output?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the article you link to shows, WCF stores the named pipe name in a memory mapped file. To access it, you need to do the following:

> - Endpoint: net.pipe://localhost/TradeService/Service1
> - Normalized Endpoint: net.pipe://+/TRADESERVICE/SERVICE1/
> - Base 64 representation: bmV0LnBpcGU6Ly8rL1RSQURFU0VSVklDRS9TRVJWSUNFMS8=
> - Final memory mapped file: net.pipe:EbmV0LnBpcGU6Ly8rL1RSQURFU0VSVklDRS9TRVJWSUNFMS8=

Now you take the final MMF name and open it. Here's an article on using MMFs on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267590(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// Open the MMF.
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(namedPipeMMFName))
{
     // Create an accessor for 16 bytes (Size of GUID) starting at 
     // offset 5 (as the article states)
     using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(5, 16))
     {
         Guid pipeGuid;
         accessor.Read<Guid>(0, out pipeGuid);
         Console.WriteLine("This should be the pipe name: " + pipeGuid);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't hink about it. This solution worked, marking as valid one.

Comment: The only change to be made here is mmf.CreateViewAccessor(4, 45). I tried 5,16 and kept getting a wrong guid

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of fiddling around and breaking my head against the wall, I finally got this working:

```
Guid pipeGuid;
if (PipeName.Equals("*", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || PipeName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     PipeName = "*";

string s = string.Format(@"net.pipe://{0}/", PipeName.ToUpper());

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceName))
     s = string.Format(@"net.pipe://*/{0}/", ServiceName.ToUpper());

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

string namedPipeMMFName = string.Format(@"Global\net.pipe:E{0}", base64);

MemoryMappedFileSecurity mSec = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
mSec.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(new     SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),  MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(namedPipeMMFName, MemoryMappedFileRights.Read))
{
    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(4, 45, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    {
        accessor.Read<Guid>(0, out pipeGuid);
    }
}

using (NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(GetResolvedText(ServerName), pipeGuid, PipeDirection.InOut,
                        PipeOptions.None, TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation))
{
    client.Connect(10000);
}
```

I must thank Rodney Viana for [his article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx) and @Avner Shahar-Kashtan for his answer and numerous other articles I read. I hope that my answer can help someone in the future.

Comment: This is fantastic--better than the accepted answer in my opinion :)..though the accepted answer does explain WHY this works.